# DateTimePicker, Solo mostrar activado el primer día del mes y el ultimo

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

Alguien tiene una idea de ¿Como hacer que el DateTimePicker solo muestre activado el primer día y el ultimo de cada mes?.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Obten la fecha actual, a esa fecha actual sácale año y mes, en base a estos 2, crea una nueva fecha new DateTime(año, mes, 1); que te dará el primer día del mes, luego a esa fecha súmale un mes, y le restas un día, eso te dará exactamente el último día del mes sin importar cuántos días tenga el mes.

Comment: puedes poner ejemplo de tu codigo? y ese datetimepicker es de que??? asp.net.... windows... mvc.... ????

Answer (score 1):

```
//Primero obtenemos el día actual
 DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

//Asi obtenemos el primer dia del mes actual
DateTime oPrimerDiaDelMes = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);

//Y de la siguiente forma obtenemos el ultimo dia del mes
//agregamos 1 mes al objeto anterior y restamos 1 día.
DateTime oUltimoDiaDelMes = oPrimerDiaDelMes.Value.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Ahora a estos parametros es decir oPrimerDiaDelMes y oUltimoDiaDelMes se lo debes pasar a tu datetimepicker.